# How to recursively traverse nested generic collection?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, recursion, icollection

I want to count the number of a class in a nested collection, e.g. [[[1,2],[3,4,5]],[[1,2],[3,4,5]]]. Here the referred class is "int" and the expected answer is 10.

I generate this list as:

```
        List<int> list1 = new List<int>(2);
        list1.Add(1);
        list1.Add(2);
        List<int> list2 = new List<int>(3);
        list2.Add(3);
        list2.Add(4);
        list2.Add(5);

        List<List<int>> listlist = new List<List<int>>(2);
        listlist.Add(list1);
        listlist.Add(list2);

        List<List<List<int>>> listlistlist = new List<List<List<int>>>(2);
        listlistlist.Add(listlist);
        listlistlist.Add(listlist);
```

When I am programing, I prefer to write such a method for a generic class, my codes are:

```
    public static int CountT<T>(ICollection<T> pTCol, int intLevel = 1)
    {
        int intCount = 0;
        if (intLevel > 0)
        {
            intLevel--;
            foreach (T pT in pTCol)
            {
                ICollection<T> subTCol = pT as ICollection<T>;   //PROBLEM: I got "null" for subTCol when the program was running
                intCount += CountT(subTCol, intLevel);
            }
        }
        else if (intLevel == 0)
        {
            intCount = pTCol.Count;
        }
        return intCount;
    }
```

I tested the above code by

```
        int intCount = CountT(listlistlist, 2);
```

then I got the problem

```
        ICollection<T> subTCol = pT as ICollection<T>;   //PROBLEM: I got "null" for subTCol when the program was running
```

I also tried the codes:

```
    public static int CountT2<T, T2>(ICollection<T> pTCol, int intLevel = 1)
    {
        int intCount = 0;
        if (intLevel > 0)
        {
            intLevel--;
            foreach (T pT in pTCol)
            {
                ICollection<T2> subTCol = pT as ICollection<T2>;
                intCount += CountT2(subTCol, intLevel);   //PROBLEM: The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. (I could not pass the compiling)
            }
        }
        else if (intLevel == 0)
        {
            intCount = pTCol.Count;
        }
        return intCount;
    }
```

I could not pass the compiling

```
        intCount += CountT2(subTCol, intLevel);   //PROBLEM: The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. (I could not pass the compiling)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Will you always have three levels, or an arbitrary number?

Comment: In my practical problem I only have two levels, but I want to implement a generic method, that is, I want to have a method that can handle an arbitrary number of levels.

Comment: I would suggest that for an arbitrary number of levels, the appropriate data structure is a **tree**, for which the algorithms are much more straightforward.

Comment: Does the **tree** mean a tree based class like `SortedSet`? I cannot see the advantage of a **tree** in my problem. Can you please show the advantage by giving an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ICollection subTCol = pT as ICollection //PROBLEM: I got "null" for subTCol**

The reason this is null is `pT` is not an `ICollection<T>` because `T` is `int` and `listlistlist` is a `List<List<List<T>>>`.  Therefore `pT` is a `List<List<T>>` which is why if you try to cast it to `ICollection<T>` you'll get null.

**I want to count the number of items in a nested collection.**

You can do this much easier using [linq](/questions/tagged/linq)'s `Sum` method.  If you know the nesting level, for example:

```
Assert.AreEqual(10, listlistlist.Sum(x => x.Sum(y => y.Count)));
```

If you don't know the nesting level or you want a more generic method, you could create an extension method like:

```
public static class RecursiveSumExtension
{
    public static int RecursiveSum(this IEnumerable items)
    {
        if (null == items)
            return 0;

        var total = 0;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item is IEnumerable)
                total += (item as IEnumerable).RecursiveSum();

            else
                total++;
        }

        return total;
    }
}
```

and the test:

```
 Assert.AreEqual(10, listlistlist.RecursiveSum());
```

**List Generation**

As a quick aside, you can use [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)'s collection initializer syntax to make the code a bit more readable when you are creating collections:

```
        var listlist = new List<List<int>>
        {
            new List<int> {1, 2},
            new List<int> {3, 4, 5}
        };

        var listlistlist = new List<List<List<int>>>
        {
            listlist,
            listlist
        };
```

Comment: I need to add `using System.Collections;` at the top of the class if I want to use `IEnumerable`.